# How to get status code from an image url? Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, http, url, get

How would you get a status code from an image url. If the image status code is 404, I'd like to replace it with something else.

Comment: You could probably use Ajax in order to determine the exact response code if needed, however this is a heavier approach compared to Arup's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) and [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onImageLoad() {
    alert("imgOne is loaded.");
  }

  function onImageLoadError() {
    alert("imgTwo is not loaded.");
  }
</script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="imgOne" onload="onImageLoad(this);" />
<img src="http://via1.placeholder.com/350x150" id="imgTwo" onerror="onImageLoadError(this);" />
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vcxt9sa/1/).

Comment: The only issue here is that you can't specifically associate it to a response code.